# Jenkins Copy from WORKSPACE of latest completed build

Tags: jenkins

When copying attributes from another build, one of the options you get on Jenkins is:

"Copy from WORKSPACE of latest completed build"

I thought that the workspace was shared between builds, so that if there is a build under way, then you'll get the workspace of the one, and not of the last completed one.

Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Each Jenkins job has a separate workspace

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski true, but the question is referring to builds, not jobs.

Comment: Yes, each job workspace contains the latest build and previous ones (their count depends on log rotation, number of builds to kept, etc). They are stored in a separate folders. You can open jobs folder in your Jenkins home and see that

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski What's in the jobs tree is the archived artifacts **not** the workspace.  The workspaces are kept under the workspace folder, and there's one per job, not per build.